# Specify similar configuration in groups of a Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bundler

We have a rails app in which we have split out apps into engines. Now we have many engines and all them have to either point to develop or master, something like

```
gem 'a', :git => "https://github.com/abc/a.git", :branch => 'develop'
gem 'b', :git => "https://github.com/abc/b.git", :branch => 'develop'
gem 'c', :git => "https://github.com/abc/c.git", :branch => 'develop'
gem 'd', :git => "https://github.com/abc/d.git", :branch => 'develop'
```

I want to group them and on the basis of the group branches are specified, something like this:

```
group :development, :branch => 'develop' do
    gem 'a', :git => "https://github.com/abc/a.git"
    gem 'b', :git => "https://github.com/abc/b.git"
    gem 'c', :git => "https://github.com/abc/c.git"
    gem 'd', :git => "https://github.com/abc/d.git"
end
```

I have gone through bundler docs but it only specifies how to add branch per gem. Is there a way to do similar configuration on a no. of gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gemfile` consists of plain Ruby, after all. You can do this:

```
%w(a b c d).each do |repo|
  gem repo,
    :git => "https://github.com/abc/#{repo}.git",
    :branch => 'develop'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Gemfile has his own DSL. But nothing prevent you to use Ruby in it:

```
branch = 'develop'

group :development do
  %(a b c d).each do |lib|
    gem lib, :git => "https://github.com/abc/#{lib}.git", :branch => branch
  end
end
```